# Monitoring changes on a View

Tags: view, change-data-capture

Many DBMS implement views. However, do some of them implement change data capture on views (rather than actual tables), in a near real time fashion ?

Answer (score 1):

I work mainly with Sql Server, but I'm not aware of any DBMS that can track changes on a '*view*'.

I would suggest that a standard view is only a logical abstraction of physical tables and does not provide any actual data storage to change. Any changes done though the view would be applied to the actual physical tables. As I understand it, CDC uses the transaction log to process the changes, I think your answer is no. If you need to track the data changes, you would need to track the underlying tables.